# Getting children elements with protractor

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

I'm new to Protractor and web development in general, I come from a Java background. I'm doing testing for a web app and I'm having issues trying to get the text from an element.

So the code is organized this way

```
<parent>
  <parent2>
    <child>
      <target-element>
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwB6X.png)
I have attached an image with the code. My problem is that there are several child elements with the same class name and tag name. I'm trying to pull them by index and then try to read the text from the target element but it returns an empty string. So from the image I'm trying to retrieve the text 'TU' from the name tag 'text' but I can't seem to be able to that. Here is one of the things I've tried.

```
var first = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis g')).get(2);
expect(first.getText()).toBe('TU');
```

I tried checking that the items are being displayed but it will only check for the first one found

```
expect(ecmSummaryTile.implementedPlot.element(by.css('.tick')).
   isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Based on these examples from Protractor docs, they only show examples with one parent element but in this case the code I'm working with is a bit more convoluted. Can anybody shed some light on how to do this?

code update
here is the structure of the code. Unfortunately I cannot give the complete code as it is massive and for my company so I cannot paste the whole source code. But the complete structure for the item I'm working with is the following

```
<div class = "ecm-summary-chart-container">
<nvd3 class = "ng-isolate-scope">
    <svg class = "nvd3-svg">
        <g class = "nvd3 nv-wrap nv-lineChart">
            <g>
                <g class="nv-legendWrap">
                    <g class="nv-focus">
                        <g class="nv-x nv-axis nvd3-svg">
                            <g class="nvd3 nv-wrap nv-axis">
                                <g>
                                    <g class="tick">
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
```

I know I could find the element using nested element(by.css) and keep going down until I get to the element, but I have multiple elements with the same class name which is why I'm not doing that

Answer (score 0):

> `var first = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis g')).get(2);`

I think you are on the right track, except that I would add a *direct parent-child relationship* here and call `first()` to get the first `g`:

```
var first = $$('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis > g').first();
var text = first.$('.tick text');

expect(text.getText()).toEqual("TU");
```

You may additionally need to wait for the element to have a `TU` value:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(text, "TU"), 10000);

expect(text.getText()).toEqual("TU");
```

Comment: I tried it that way and had the same response. I would believe returning an empty string is the correct response as the first g is just a parent for all the other g's that actually contain the values I'm trying to retrieve
I tried changing it to var first = $$('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis > g').get(1); but still got the same problem, it returns an empty string  Expected '' to equal 'TU'

Comment: @JoseHernandez okay, updated with one more guess, check it out.

Comment: that didn't seem to help, I kept getting errors stating that there were multiple elements found and would select the first one followed by a timeout error. I tried updating the waiting time and using get() instead of first() but didn't get any better results

Comment: @JoseHernandez okay, no problem, could you post the complete HTML source of the page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be locator  you mentioned is incorrect(forgot to include one more tag '*g*'). Hope below code will resolve your issue.

Code Snippet:

```
 element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g>g')).each(function(element, 
        index) {
            // will get each element
             element.getText().then(function (text) {
             console.log(index, text);
              });
           });
```

Comment: this seems to work when printing the elements, but if I try to use '>g>g' along with the other options such as first() or get() I am still unable to retrieve the values. It could be that I'm targeting the wrong parent element. I need to look into it. when running I get the following output
0 ''
1 ''
2 ''
3 ''
4 ''
5 ''
6 ''
7 ''
8 ''
9 ''
10 'TU'
11 'WE'
12 'TH'
13 'FR'
14 'SA'
15 'SU'
16 'MO'
17 ''
18 'TU'
19 'WE'
20 'TH'
21 'FR'
22 'SA'
23 'SU'
24 'MO'
25 ''
26 ''
27 ''
28 ''
29 ''
30 'TH'
31 'FR'
32 'SA'
33 'SU'
34 'MO'
35 'TU'
36 'WE'

Comment: element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g>g')).first().then(function(ele){ ele.getText().then(function(txt){
     console.log(txt)
}
);
});

Comment: @JoseHernandez try above one, if not working. add my skype id -'sallojusuresh'. i can help you

Comment: I got an error and after a quick search I updated it to 
var x = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g>g')).first();
 x.getText().then(function(txt) {
             console.log("txt: " + txt);
            });
I is stillget an empty string.

Comment: I see in the logs that " more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis) - the first result will be used"
However I don't see another one that follow the same structure within the html code but it's possible that protractor is finding another element. I will try a few more things and see if I can solve it
@SureshSalloju, I will add you and let you know if I keep running into this issue. Thanks

Comment: so I did the following var foo = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g text')); expect(foo.getText()).toBe('TU'); and got Expected [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', '', '', '', '0', '8', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', '', '', '', '', '0', '106', '', '', '0', '37', '', '', '', '0', '1', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', 'TU', 'WE', '' ] to be 'TU'.

Comment: looking at this the answer I need is at index = 14, so I did 
var foo = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g text')).get(14);
            expect(foo.getText()).toBe('TU');

this works but it's still incorrect since I would need to know the exact index of the value I need. Not sure where the bunch of empty strings is coming from nor why the values are also being repeated in the output

Comment: I can't copy and paste the whole view here. I can add you on skyoe and show you so you can see it

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried this?

```
var text = $('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis > g').get(2);

expect(text.getText()).toEqual("TU");
```

Comment: so I did the following 
var foo = element.all(by.css('.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis>g text'));
            expect(foo.getText()).toBe('TU');

and got  Expected [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', '', '', '', '0', '8', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', '', '', '', '', '0', '106', '', '', '0', '37', '', '', '', '0', '1', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'MO', 'TU', 'WE', '' ] to be 'TU'.